# Why Do Browsers Leak Memory?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, browser

A colleague and I were speaking about browsers (using browser control in a project), and it appears as plain as day that all browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE, Opera) display the same characteristic or side-effect from their usage and that being 'Leaking Memory'.

Can someone explain why that is the case? 
Surely as with any form of code, there should be proper garbage collection?

- PS. I've read about some defensive patterns on why this can happen from a developer's perspective. I am aware of an article Crockford wrote on IE; but why is the problem symptomatic of every browser?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: This is better suited for [programmers.se]

Comment: you might as well ask "why does code have bugs?"

Comment: Ok perhaps the category is wrong - but my question is not how do I better implement my code to prevent 'memory leaks', but rather why are browsers poor at memory usage? Take any browser you may have and run a simple test by continuous refreshing, and you will end up with a 'leak'? Remembering HTTP is stateless - so when I move away from a page, why should there be any remnant?